# Displaying a HTML page in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, plugins, browser

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and am writing some HTML and JavaScript code.

My question is this: Is it possible to display the code I write in a browser, rather than having to open up a browser and then browse to the HTML file that I have written?

Is there native support for this? Do I need an extension or something similar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to DEBUG-->Start Without Debugging, and it will run it and auto-open the html page in a browser for you.  Or you can press Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

If the project you are working on is a web application, then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to 'Start Without Debugging' as mentioned in JClark4321's answer.

If you are working on something that is *not* a web application then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to open the file in the browser or you can just right click the file in the Solution Explorer and click 'View in Browser'. This also prevents Visual Studio from compiling the project just to view a HTML file.

Another thing you can do is simply open the HTML file and switch to Design or Split view (bottom left corner of Visual Studio when editing a HTML file).

Comment: View in Browser is not listed as an option in Solution Explorer.